# Points of intersection between circle and parabola

Tags: circles, roots

Find the points of intersection between circle and a parable:

circle: $x^2 + y^2 - 2x + 4y - 11 = 0$

parable: $y = (-x^2+ 2x + 1 - 2\sqrt{3})$

I don't understand how to solve this, I really tried, but was useless.

If anyone can help me, I am very grateful.

Comment: Or simply add the two equations:  all terms involving powers of x cancel...

Answer (score 1):

The point at which the circle and parabola interect, $(x_0,y_0),$ satisfies both equations, so

$x_0^2+y_0^2-2x_0+4y_0-11=0 \tag{1}$

$\color{green}{y_0=-x_0^2+2x_0+1-2\sqrt{3}} \tag{2}$

Now, solve $(1)$ and $(2)$ simultaneously!

Hint: substitute $\color{green}{y_0=-x_0^2+2x_0+1-2\sqrt{3}}$ into $(1)$ to give:

$$x_0^2+[\color{green}{-x_0^2+2x_0+1-2\sqrt{3}}]^2-2x_0+4[\color{green}{-x_0^2+2x_0+1-2\sqrt{3}}]-11=0 \tag{3}.$$

Solve $(3)$, for $x_0$.

Once you have solved $(3)$ for $x_0$, sub this into either $(1)$ or $(2)$ to find $y_0$.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to solve by your way, but I failed. If you can show me how to solve step by step. Will be great.

Comment: I still can not solve this problem... :(

Comment: You've got a quadratic equation in $x_0$.
Simplify equation $(3)$ and solve for $x_0$.

Comment: Ok, I will try. ;)

Comment: So, I found this equation:

$$x_0^4 - 4x_0³ + (4\sqrt{3} - 1)x_0² + (10 - 8\sqrt{3})x_0 + 6 - 12\sqrt{3} = 0.$$

But I don't know how to proceed now, how to solve this equation.

Comment: We've got a quartic, so guess the roots and then factorise it as:
$(x_0-3)(x_0+1)\underbrace{(x_0^2-2x_0+4\sqrt{3}-2)}_{\text{solve using quadratic formula}}=0$.

Comment: You should get **two** real roots (ignore the strcitly complex ones), which you should use to find $y_0$.

Comment: Ok, I think I understood. But I don't understand how you do the factorization of the equation.

Comment: I guesses the roots (always start with $\pm 1, \pm 2,$ etc.) until I found two exact roots (3 and -1); I then factorised the equation as $(x_0-3)(x_0+1)(ax_0^2+bx_0+c)=0$.

By inspection (comparing $x_0^4$ terms, etc. on the LHS and RHS, one can find $a$, $b$ and $c$ (which are constants).